# How is the number of flags for moderation attention calculated?

Tags: support, flags

While answering to a question, I checked the number of flags for moderation attention I could use in a day, and I have noticed the following:

```
Site                     |Reputation | Number of flags
------------------------------------------------------
Super User               |       812 |       23
Ask Different            |      1317 |       15   
Seasoned Advice          |      2776 |       23
Meta Stack Overflow      |     23398 |       45
English Language & Usage |     25506 |       50
```

The value that seems higher, when compared to the reputation, is the one for *Super User*, who is equal to the number of flags for moderation attention I have on *Seasoned Advice*.

How is the number of flags for moderation attention calculated?

Comment: I think your number of "helpful flags" on a site plays into that (in addition to reputation.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calculation is detailed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890). Basically, every day you get:

- 10 flags by default
- one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
- one bonus flag per 10 *net* helpful flags (helpful minus declined)
- a maximum of 100

… so it does depend on your reputation, but you also get bonus flags depending on your flagging history.

Comment: There's no flag weight now. Did number of helpful flags affect number of flags per day somehow?

Comment: @RiaD Obviously this is outdated now. I guess I can update it since there's a good source...