# On the recent changes to flagging and limits

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags, rate-limiting

Looks like flagging has been affected by releases today. Are these intended effects?

- Higher daily limits (appear doubled for me, flagging of posts limit also doubled).  *Explained by Shog9 below.*
- <strike>Soft comment deletion [doesn't appear to work anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185891/in-place-soft-deletion-for-accept-rate-comments-has-stopped-working) - e.g. for "accept rate" obsolete comments - it does in fact work, but the immediate feedback is gone.</strike>  *This is fixed now*.
- <strike>Has the throttling rate changed?  Seems possible to repeated flag without waiting 5 seconds.</strike>  *If it was broken, it isn't anymore.*
- Old soft deletions that were neither categorised as "helpful" or "declined" have all become "helpful".

<strike>If limits have been updated, can we get the new formula published?</strike> *Not changed, as confirmed by Shog9.*

Comment: The soft-deletion thing sounds like a bug. If you can verify, please post it as one.

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185891/in-place-soft-deletion-for-accept-rate-comments-has-stopped-working):  After a bit more investigation, turns out it is working, but the immediate feedback isn't.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You start with 10 flags per day.

Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as many as 100 per day.

Currently, that means you get an extra flag per day for every 2000 reputation points or 10 *net* helpful flags (helpful-declined).

Since you have an insane number of helpful flags, you're maxed out at 100 per day.

Comment: A whole bunch of old flags of mine got marked as helpful, so the number went up by about 5K today.

Comment: Oh, comment flags show up in history now? That’s nice.

Comment: Also, you're no longer able to flag as both Needs Mod Attention(NaN & VLQ) and as Spam/Offensive.

Comment: Do you get your flags back if they are marked as helpful on the same day you flagged them (like Close Votes)?

Comment: No, @hichris123

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, wondered why I was running out of flags! I wish I could close vote, but don't have enough rep. Not a problem for you though. :)

Comment: You're a third of the way there, @hichris123... Nothing wrong with answering questions.

Comment: So if you have more unhelpful flags than helpful does this mean that you will lose the amount of daily flags limit?

Comment: You *could*, @puretppc.

Comment: But if it reaches 0 (-100 in terms of helpful/unhelpful flags) I guess you're not allowed to flag then unless you gain 2k rep?

Comment: Disputed count as unhelpful?

Comment: Disputed doesn't count for anything, @3ventic

Comment: Can you request more flags from a moderator?

Comment: No, you get more the next day @Tom.