# In-place soft deletion for "accept rate" comments has stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

Soft deletions of comments used to have a satisfying feature that the comment vanished when flagged.  Although soft deletion still works, a page refresh is required to see the affect.

[This Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/54294/candidate-obsolete-comments-mentioning-accept-rate) can be used to find test candidates.  It shows posts where acceptance is mentioned in a comment and the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: This seems like a perfect opportunity to replace the page-refresh with an animation of the comment being dragged screaming into the abyss.

Comment: @Shog9 don't forget eaten by a giant fire unicorn first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

We made some backend changes and didn't notice this particular issue.