# Any known issues with the review flags?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, 10k-tools

This morning I notices two issues:

1. I can do as much as 100 flags instead of usually 48.
2. I still see the posts I have flagged which is not the case usually, I can not flag them again but they are still there, this makes it difficult to determine which posts are really available.

Answer (score 2):

The number-of-flags algorithm just got changed. See Shog9's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/215468).

Here's the fundamentals of his answer reproduced here:

> - you start with 10 flags per day.
> - 100 per day max.
> - extra flag for every 2000 reputation
> - extra flag for every 10 net helpful flags (helpful-unhelpful).

You have 12k rep, so that's an additional **6** flags, bringing you up to 16. That means that you have at least, umm, let's see here, **820** net helpful flags, bringing your total to 100, which is the max.

Also, you have always been able to see the posts you have flagged.

Comment: Thank you, regarding the posts i have flagged i could see them under reviews history, but as soon i flag a post under review->tools and refresh the page the post i have handled was gone, and the number of available posts for that category (for example "not an answer") would decrease