# How do you get more flags?

Tags: support, flags

Once I flag a question, does that mean I can **never ever ever ever** get that flag back? For example I currently have 10 flags on superuser, if I were to flag a post would I permanently have 9? If not, how would I get that flag back?

Comment: Go to bed, wake up the next day, problem solved. And you get more if you flag well.

Comment: As you can tell from the above-linked question, flags are replenished daily. The number is calculated based on the values in the linked answer.

Answer (score 10):

Flags are reset at the end of each UTC day.  You will have new flags after midnight.

You get additional flags per day for every 2000 points of reputation you get and for each 10 helpful flags you have (whilst unhelpful flags reduce your flag availability).  *[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/176080)*

Comment: Do you have to have both 2000 points and 10 helpful flags?

Comment: Nope, if you flag well 10 times you're rewarded with an additional flag, the reputation link is just a bonus (and a new one at that)

Comment: What types of flags are considered "unhelpful"?  I'm assuming you mean declined, disputed, and aged away.  I could see aged away and disputed as more neutral though.