# Daily limit of flags increase?

Tags: support, flags, limits

I have noticed that my daily limit of flags. On the attached picture it says "66 remaining flags" but it was much less several of weeks ago (about 40+ or 50+)

[image: Flags remaining]

Is is a **feature** (with amount of helpful flag growth, the flag daily limit grows ) or were there any **limit changes** on SO recently?

**Update:**
That question has been answered here: [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/205246)

Comment: As Shog mentioned [in the link that Mat referenced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/164243)m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Shog mentioned [in the link that Mat referenced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/164243) , you're getting an extra flag-per-day per 2000, plus an initial default of 10.

So on SO you have 5800+ reputation, that means you're getting the daily bonus of flags. Basically the math works out, you're doing fine.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I had to edit because I had misunderstood math a little

Comment: I saw your answer with the calculations and I think it was very close to the correct value as I have _used_ two or three flags today.