# How does the flags remaining count equation work?

Tags: support, flags

How does the flags remaining count equation work?

- How many I've got per day?
- The number of flags remaining depends on my actives, declined, helpfuls, what else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How many I've got per day?

Every user starts 10 flags per day (maximum is 100 flags per day)

> The number of flags remaining depends on my actives, declined, helpfuls,...?

Yes, your activity (that is reputation and flagging history) affects your remaining flag count.  You get an extra flag per day for every 2000 reputation points or 10 net helpful flags (helpful-unhelpful).

Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/