# How to flag a flag?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I've found a question that's incorrectly flagged as an duplicate.
I'm not the author of the question.
Still, I would like to request moderator intervention regarding the flag.

How do I do that?
One solution could be flagging the question once more, like so:

[image]
But this solution is not clean.
Furthermore, it has some undesired effects beyond purity:

1. It [uses up my daily flag limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226000/358406) (marked in the picture above)
2. It might have some negative consequences for the author of the question.
3. Most probably, it does not have any consequences whatsoever for the author of the incorrect flag. Whereas, it should have. E.g. some minor decrement to reputation score.

Comment: As an aside, incorrect flags will *never* affect your reputation, and there is no reputation penalty for incorrect flags. Users with too many declined flags may end up temporarily banned from flagging more posts, but that requires [a lot of flags to be declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405), not just one.

Comment: Yes, I've researched that prior to asking. Still, incorrect flags may prompt proactive StackExchange users, like me, to do sth about them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not need to do anything.

If the flag has not merit, it will either age away or be declined by a moderator.

Comment: "_…or be declined by a moderator_" Well, hopefully. How do I request moderator's intervention in case an incorrect flag remains unnoticed ?

Comment: @vucalur You don't. Because it doesn't matter. If it remains unnoticed it will age away, it'll go away if enough people decline it in review, too. Remember, five people need to cast agreeing votes for it to actually be closed as a dupe. Also a post can always be reopened if closed. It's really not an issue. Just ignore it.

Comment: Ok. Clearly, I must read up on _flags ageing_ mechanism in order to be able to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth remembering that close votes often go through a queue and *close votes* not *flags* are the proper way to do it. Your flag feeds into a close queue for review. To a pretty large extent, this isn't the sort of extraordinary circumstance that usually needs a moderator to step in.

As such *chances* are any closure has been reviewed by at least 5 users with at least 3000 reputation or a mod or a user with a gold tag badge (or any combination of it). They, hopefully, should have some idea of how things work.

On many sites (look around your local meta), there's a practice of making a case for reopening a question on meta. Might be worth a try if it's something your site practices, and if you are convinced you can make a convincing arguement for it.

If it's possible to make edits that clarify the question within the intent of the original poster, it would also throw the question into the reopen queue.