# Why is useful to flag a post in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, stackexchange.com, helpful-flags

I just started to review posts in Stack Overflow. By [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), I know why flagging is important. But:

1. Does it have any impact on my reputation?
2. What is the impact on my profile if I have a lot of helpful or declined flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No
2. None *(kinda ... except for badges ... and flag counts visible to you)*

All it really achieves is help keeping the site clean, friendly, useful, etc. In the event of a moderator election and you nominating yourself it might be useful to have a good flag count and helpful percentage. But that's about it.

It's more about helping to keep the site be something you want to come back to, rather than directly doing something for your own profile.

Comment: There *are* a few badges to be earned, but one is super easy (just flag *one* thing), the other relatively hard and (500 helpful flags). You better be doing it for the good of the site, not the badge, by that time.

Comment: Oops, I skipped over Deputy, at 80 helpful flags. But again, you should be flagging to be helpful, not to hunt for a badge.

Comment: In summary "There's this badge, ooh and that one, and another ... IGNORE THE BADGES" @MartijnPieters :p

Comment: Well, badges have an impact on the profile, so your item 2 is not strictly true.

Comment: Addressed @MartijnPieters. I wouldn't want to lose valuable MSE rep.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters. and why you earn bonus flag per 10 helpful flag and not losing flag when you have more declined flag?!

Comment: @NimaSoroush: see [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890), you do lose available flags if you get flags declined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: but it doesn't means that you can reach to 0 or minus flag when you have just declined flag. right?

Comment: You probably will be banned from flagging long before anyway.

Comment: @NimaSoroush: no, you won't go below 10. You *can* be banned from flagging if you push it far enough.